# PHP: Path of interface

Tags: php, interface, path

I need to know the path of a file in which an interface is defined. I know the name and the interface is available (the file was included at another location in the code). I know things like `__FILE__`, etc. but the point is, it's only an interface, i do not have an instance. Ironically, i need the path to find a suitable implementation for the interface.

Does anyone know a way to find the path?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the name, [ReflectionClass](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) works on interfaces too. So you can use

```
$interface = new ReflectionClass('IFoo');
echo $interface->getFilename();
```